# When using Charles Proxy with mobile devices, how can I allow a device?

Tags: proxy, android

I have Charles Proxy working fine for requests from OSX, and one Android device works fine. I have another android device with the same proxy settings on which Chrome just responds "Unable to connect to the proxy server" (ERR_PROXY_CONNECTION_FAILED).

With this second device, I was never prompted to allow it, which I suspect is the cause of this problem. How can I allow the device for use with Charles?

Answer (score 3):

Here are some troubleshooting tips to try:

1. Validate that the Mac/PC running Charles Proxy are on the same network (Presumably wifi). You may be able to ping the mobile device from the Mac/PC Charles Host.
2. On the Android device make sure that in the wifi settings you have Advanced Config Checked, and have pointed the device to the IP address of the Charles Proxy Host. Also, be sure you have the correct port set, which I believe is 8888 by default.
3. On the android device, open the Chrome Browser and goto charlesproxy.com/getssl and install the SSL root certificate for you specific Host.
4. You may need to turn wifi on/off on the phone or even reboot the phone if step 3 does not work. I believe some Android devices don't dynamically write the network changes and restart (down/up) the wifi interface as they seem to display.